# Dropdown menu in custom navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a nav bar for my website which I got from an online template. I made some necessary changes in code and made it suitable for my project. But I'm unable to add a drop down menu. How can I add dropdown menu in the main menu.

Here is the code

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font: normal .80em 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #555;
}

p {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#menubar {
    width: 880px;
    height: 46px;
}

ul#menu {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 9px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
    background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a {
    font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

ul#menu li.selected a {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
}

ul#menu li.selected {
    margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
    background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover {
    background: #00C6F0 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
    color: #FFF;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #E4EC04;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="post.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ref="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
            <li><a ref="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a ref="#">Members</a></li>
            <li><a ref="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a ref="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed many online tutorials. But I couldn't display drop down sub menu arrow for above main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
html{ height: 100%;}

*
{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
body
{ font: normal .80em 'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #555;}

nav{
    margin-top:15px
}

nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
  max-width:700px;
  width:100%;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center; 
}

nav ul a{
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  align-self:center;
}

nav ul li{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li.current-menu-item{
    background: gray;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
  color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
  background: #5A5A5A url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding:0
}

nav ul ul li{
    float:none;
    width:200px;
  background: #5a5a5a;
}

nav ul ul a{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
   color: white !important;
}

nav ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}

/* standard */
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size:15px
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <!-- put class="selected" in the li tag for the selected page - to highlight which page you're on -->
      <li ><a  href="#" >Home</a></li>

      <li  ><a  ref="#" >Projects</a></li>
      <li  ><a href="#" >Publications</a></li>
         <li  ><a  ref="#"  >News</a></li>
      <li ><a ref="#" >Members</a></li>
      <li ><a  ref="#" >Gallery</a></li>
      <li ><a ref="#" >Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Dark</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Basic Light</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Playful</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Elegant</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The dropdown menu disappers when trying to select submenu and sometime only it stays.

Comment: I've updated the answer, create it with flex and make it more stable

Comment: But i have an id name main menubar and menu...what you did is with nav.

Comment: To be in the top page and declared in browser is a navbar, check [HTML Semantic Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), and how it work + I remove that id's and classes you don't need it because you will have just one `<nav>` tag in your HTML so you already have unique tag so you don't need to add more classes and ID's to your styling